# PayPal Express Checkout Instant Update CallbackURL not being called in live setup

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working on integrating PayPal Express Checkout into an existing web application using Zen Cart .

Everything, including the Instant Update Callback, works fine in a setup that uses Sandbox settings. The Callback works fine both on HTTP and HTTPS in the Sandbox. But as soon as I switch to Live credentials, the PayPal UI stops hitting the CallbackURL and falls back to using the (fall back) shipping costs sent in SetExpressCheckout.

I'm using the latest version of the PayPal PHP SDK . The only settings that are changed to switch the setup from Sandbox to Live are:

```
UserName
Password
Signature
mode (from sandbox to live)
```

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated. The SSL is certified by mainstream SSL issuing company.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a business account? Are you verified?
I'm just throwing guesses as I just worked on part of API that requires verified bussiness account.
Did you check out the call output? It'd be better if you posted source code.